# Can I combine these two array into one object using React and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

While working on my application I found out that the way I have it set up now is not really ideal. I am currently saving the values of two dynamicly created input fields in two seperate arrays. Now as I understand this is not really smart to do since both input fields have the same index and actually belong together.

Now I was wondering how I can change my code so I can save both values in the same Object.

This is my code for my dynamic form:

```js
class MediaInput extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const linkName = `link${this.props.index}`;
    const contentName = `content${this.props.index}`;

    return (
      <div>
      <ControlLabel>Media (optional)</ControlLabel>
        <input
        onChange={(event) => this.props.handleChangeUrl(event, this.props.index)}
        name={ linkName }
        value={ this.props.mediaUrls[this.props.index]}
        className="form-control"
        placeholder="Add your media url. We accept YouTube, Vimeo and SoundCloud links" 
        type="text" 
        />
        <input
        name={ contentName }
        onChange={(event) => this.props.handleChangeContent(event, this.props.index)}
        value={ this.props.mediaContents[this.props.index]}
        className="form-control" 
        placeholder="Add your media content"
        type="text" 
        />
    </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This is my current state:

```js
    this.state ={
      mediaFields: [],
      content: [],
      mediaUrls: [ null, null, null ],
      mediaContents: ['', '', ''],
    };
```

These are my functions:

```js
// Add/remove media fields 

  add() {
    event.preventDefault();
    const mediaFields = this.state.mediaFields.concat(MediaInput);
    if (i < 3) {
      this.setState({ mediaFields });
      i++
    } else {
      Bert.alert('Only 3 media links are allowed', 'danger');
    }
  }

  remove() {
    event.preventDefault();
    const lastElement = this.state.mediaFields.pop();
    const mediaFields = this.state.mediaFields;
    this.setState({ mediaFields });
    i--
  }

// Handle change media fields 

  handleChangeUrl(e, index) {
    // Shallow copy of array
    const mediaUrls = this.state.mediaUrls.slice();
    let url = e.target.value
    if (!/^https?:\/\//i.test(url)) {
      url = 'http://' + url;
    }

    mediaUrls[index] = url;
      this.setState({ mediaUrls});
  }

  handleChangeContent(e, index) {
    // Shallow copy of array
    const mediaContents = this.state.mediaContents.slice();
    mediaContents[index] = e.target.value;
      this.setState({ mediaContents });
  }
```

And this is the part of the form where I add the input fields:

```js
[...]
 
const mediaFields = this.state.mediaFields.map((Element, index) => {
      return <Element key={ index } index={ index } mediaUrls={this.state.mediaUrls} mediaContents={this.state.mediaContents} handleChangeUrl={this.handleChangeUrl} handleChangeContent={this.handleChangeContent} />
  })    

 
[...]


<div>
    { mediaFields }
    <Button onClick={ () => this.add() }>Add media field</Button>
    <Button onClick={ () => this.remove() }>Remove media field</Button>
</div>
```

As you can see I have almost the same function and I understand that this is not great, so I want to learn how I can do it better.

I want to save both the values in the same Object. Like so:

```js
const mediaContent = [ link1: content1, link2: content2, link3: content3 ]
```

Hope someone can push me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Javascript, an array can only be indexed by a number (it is not like PHP).

That being said, you can have both values, like you want, in an object (json).

So, you would have something like:

```
const mediaContent = { link1: content1, link2: content2, link3: content3 }
```

Then, you just need to treat your object like an array. An object doesn't have the methods `pop` and `concat`, but it can be easily achieved using [Object.Assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) for adding, and [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) + map reducing functions to remove (actually treating your object again as array).

**Extra tip: You can remove the `i` variable and use Object.keys(this.state.mediaFields).length instead.**

```js
 add() {
   event.preventDefault();
   const mediaFields = Object.assign(this.state.mediaFields, MediaInput);
   if (i < 3) {
     this.setState({ mediaFields });
     i++;
   } else {
     Bert.alert('Only 3 media links are allowed', 'danger');
   }
 }
```

```js
  remove() {
    event.preventDefault();
    
    const mediaFields = Object.keys(this.state.mediaFields)
      .map(k => this.state.mediaFields[k])
      .pop()
      .reduce((items, curr) => ({
        ...items,
        curr
      }), {});
    
    this.setState({ mediaFields });
    i--
  }
```

**Be aware that keeping the order for adding and removing might not work properly.**

Comment: I actually just managed to get the arrays in an object by using: "const mediaObject = _.zipObject(mediaUrls, mediaContents);"

But now I ran into an other problem. How to map over this array and use both of these values. It seems like in most cases only one of these values are being used....

Comment: `Object.keys(mediaObject).map(url => { const content = mediaObject[url] }` should do the trick

Comment: I don't completely understand. Sorry I have not slept last night... :p  What should this return? When I try to console.log(content), it says it's not defined. When I add this function to a const and try to log that I get back "[undefined, undefined]"

Comment: Lol, go rest a little :P Object.keys return the keys of an object: so, if your object is const mediaContent = { link1: content1, link2: content2, link3: content3 }, Object.keys(mediaContent) => [link1, link2, link3]. Once you have this array, you can map through it, and accessing mediaContent[key] will return you the respectively content, for example, the first iteration would be mediaContent[link1], and its value would be content1.

Comment: Well that was my problem... I actually have two different arrays at the moment. One with the links and one with the content. What I need to do is map over both (at the same time) and generate a new component where I use these values. 
I thought to solve this by creating an Object with them but I don't think that is the solution.

Comment: But that is the point, with the object you will be iterating only one time (through the keys of object) and then you can access the object itself given the key